# How to query specific mongodb mapreduce fields?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, field

How do I query for specific fields in a collection produced from mongodb mapReduce?
What should I enter to retrieve only the lastname field in the output collection?
The result should be:
{ "lastname" : "Doe" }

> > version()
>   version: 2.2.2
>   > db.test.save( { first: "John", last: "Doe" } )
>   >db.test.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("50bc001a8e97247957c6000f"), "first" : "John", "last" : "Doe" }
>   > db.test.mapReduce( 
> function() { emit( this._id, {firstname:this.first, lastname:this.last} ) } , function(key, value) { return null; }, {out: {reduce: 'output'}} )
>   {
>       "result" : "output",
>       "timeMillis" : 6,
>       "counts" : {
>           "input" : 1,
>           "emit" : 1,
>           "reduce" : 0,
>           "output" : 1
>       },
>       "ok" : 1,
>   }
>   
>   >db.output.find()
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("50bc001a8e97247957c6000f"), "value" : { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe" } }
>   >db.output.find( {}, {_id:0} )
>   { "value" : { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe" } }

Comment: I supppose you've already tried >db.output.find( {}, {lastname:1} ) ?

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("50bc001a8e97247957c6000f") }

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could come with a `find` without reworking your map-reduce would be:

```
db.output.find( {}, {_id:0, 'value.lastname':1} )
```

Comment: { "value" : { "lastname" : "Doe" } }

Comment: What would be another way to rework the map-reduce to produce those results?

Comment: @pent What are you actually trying to do with this?  It's sort of a nonsensical map-reduce in its current form.

Comment: @pent I was thinking there was a way to flatten the output to remove the `value` level but it appears there isn't: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517